# How to validate new users against a legacy database before they are registered / authenticated?

Tags: firebase-authentication

We are creating an app that allows users of our another legacy application to use a mobile app. We are using Google Sign-in in one of the apps and Mobile Number sign-in in another. Before these users can be registered to use mobile app, we need to validate them against the legacy user database and allow them to register for mobile app only if they are an existing user with that email or mobile number in the legacy user database.

Any suggestions how we can accomplish this to restrict application access to those limited users only?